# WYGWAM + Font Awesome icon chooser. Possible?

Tags: wygwam, fontawesome

I saw the "Font Awesome" plugin for CKEditor and got hyped, but couldn't get it to work.

https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/fontawesome

But that seeded the question: Is there a way to get a Font Awesome icon chooser inside WYGWAM? Or frankly any way to make it easy for content authors to choose icons for links with Expression Engine 5?

For now I use a Grid field, where it takes a Link Title, URL, and Font Awesome icon, that generates a list of links with icons. e.g., "Cool Website", "https://www.coolwebsite.com", "external-link". For this my authors have to visit the Font Awesome website. Not the worst solution, but an integrated solution would be better.